# Background color of inline code should match background color of code blocks

Tags: feature-request, design, dark-mode

With the dark theme, the background color of inline code is gray, while the background color of the code blocks is black:

[image]

This disturbs me a little. IMHO these two background colors should be identical, for better readability and better aesthetic.

What do you think of my suggestion? Do you agree?

I didn't check the background colors of the light theme.

Comment: Already reported on MSE: [The background of inline code is different from the background of code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353565/289905).

Answer (score 7):

```
A code block's background color
```

`does not need to match inline code's background color` as they serve different purposes. And indeed, in light mode, they differ, with a code block having a lighter gray than an inline run of code.

In my opinion, as long as the code block's background has sufficient contrast with the background of the surrounding post, I'm good.

[CertainPerformance, in a related post on the then-new design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353550/194720) has noted, rightfully, that the contrast between the code block's background color and the background color of the post is quite low, and perhaps insufficient.

Comment: *as long as the code block's background has sufficient contrast with the background of the surrounding post* Though, I [don't think it does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353550) in light mode

Comment: @CertainPerformance And that's a valid critique; the ratio is only 1.08:1; practically identical. It's enough for me, and that's obviously the most important thing ;-)

Comment: Given that even with the old theme `code` blocks `were` prone `to` mis-use, it would be best to make these as similar as possible.

Comment: @usr2564301 I really doubt that making the colors more similar will make the misuse any better. Misusers gonna misuse.